# How to add internal libraries into build with QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, shared-libraries, qt-creator, libraries

I'm developing an application with QT creator.

*I want to build an application that doesn't need any external libraries, but it should have all libraries included in his build* I want this to resolve the follow problem:

if I run the application through the IDE (qtcreator), the program run without any problems, if I run it through the terminal (with **"./application"**) it prints me the follow error:

> /home/helias/software/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/libexec/QtWebEngineProcess: error while
>   loading shared libraries: libQt5WebEngineCore.so.5: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory

So, how can I integrate the libraries into the release of the application to don't meet any problems with libraries?

Answer (score 3):

Deploying Qt apps (as with any application) requires you to have the required libraries in the loader search path. Qt Creator probably sets the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable when running applications or sets the RPATH of the built executable. Run **ldd** on your application to see what libraries can't be found:

```
$ ldd ./application
```

This will print the required libraries and their locations:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc63cc3000)
libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /usr/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007f8a89e04000)
libQt5WebEngineCore.so.5 => /usr/lib/libQt5WebEngineCore.so.5 (0x00007f8a85467000)
libQt5Quick.so.5 => /usr/lib/libQt5Quick.so.5 (0x00007f8a84e7f000)
libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007f8a846fc000)
libQt5Qml.so.5 => /usr/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5 (0x00007f8a8410b000)
libQt5Network.so.5 => /usr/lib/libQt5Network.so.5 (0x00007f8a83d9f000)
libQt5WebChannel.so.5 => /usr/lib/libQt5WebChannel.so.5 (0x00007f8a83b82000)
libQt5Positioning.so.5 => /usr/lib/libQt5Positioning.so.5 (0x00007f8a83942000)
libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f8a83278000)
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f8a83007000)
libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f8a82dea000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f8a82a68000)
```

etc.

If the loader can't find libraries it will tell you **NOT FOUND**. In that likely case you either make them available in the appropriate place by installing them, or copying the libraries to a directory in the executable's **RPATH**. The easiest would be to install the Qt libraries for your distribution. As you can see with my ldd output, mine are installed as they are found in /usr/lib. The required package will be different on every Linux distribution.

The authoritative source for deploying Qt applications seems to be [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment.html).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to bind the libraries required by Qt framework into your application?

If that so then read the license terms first, as if i'm understanding your need, you are building application with static libraries, which is not allowed by free or LGPL version of Qt, for that you need to buy the commercial version.

For building the application with static libraries you can refer to voidrealms.com tutorial for building application with statically linked libraries.